# Building fragment stack for One Activity Many Fragment App

Tags: android, android-fragments, stack, android-notifications, up-navigation

My App has **only one activity** and **lots of fragments**.

In my activty's XML, I just have a `FrameLayout` on which I replace/add/hide/show various fragments.

Imagine `Fragment A` is the first fragment the user sees when they open the app.

Click something in `Fragment A` to launch `Fragment B` and click something in `Fragment B` to launch `Fragment C`.

So the navigation is can be illustrated as follows :

**Fragment A  --> Fragment B -->  Fragment C**

I want to launch the app and show `Fragment C` directly from notification.

However, how can I provide back navigation from `Fragment C`, as such clicking back would go to `Fragment B` and clicking back again go to `Fragment A` ?

i.e How can I inject the following stack structure ?

**Fragment A  <-- Fragment B <-- Fragment C**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Since support library v26 you can build the stack with fragments without significant cost. 
In your activity make the following:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentA())
            .addToBackStack("fragmentA")
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentB())
            .addToBackStack("fragmentB")
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new FragmentC())
            .addToBackStack("fragmentC")
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .commit();
```

Keep in mind that FragmentA and FragmentB will behave in a bit different way after pressing back on FragmentC due to setReorderingAllowed. onCreateView won't be called for FragmentA and FragmentB after they were added to stack, only in FragmentC onCreateView will be called. For FragmentA and FragmentB only onCreate will be called.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is - 
Use a notification intent in which you pass a string. In your main activity if you receive that string make a fragment stack of A, B and C.
Else if you don't get the intent just continue your flow as it is.

Comment: "make a fragment stack of A, B and C" that is my question, how do I do it? There are ways to create an activity stack, in order to maintain navigational integrity, when launching app from notification.

Comment: What I meant was you use fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(str) when you get lets say- getIntent().hasExtra(Constant.FROM_NOTIFICATION) otherwise you go ahead as it is.

Comment: the add to back stack method-
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragmentB);
 ft.addToBackStack("fragB");
    ft.commit(); and then for fragment c

Comment: Sorry, that is not stack injection. That is normally adding fragments one by one. It will cause the user to see A ,B and C being added one by one.

Comment: Do this in onStart. User sees Ui only once on resume has been called.

Comment: @NoobDogg did you try?

Comment: Yeah doesn't work, it partially does but doesn't scale, thanks for helping out.